# Android : how to add multiple images on a layout with zoom,pan,scale functionality

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, zooming, pan

I am making an application which will work like this :

- I will have a viewpager
- each pager element will be an image as background
- I need to have the ability to add custom objects (other small images) on this background and to move and scale
- I need the functionality to zoom the whole page with all the objects on it zooming as well with the background

Can you help me on this ?

thank you

Comment: We did the following : we layd down the objects on a background, we can move, scale BUT we cannot zoom the whole page and keep zooming the background and objects on it too.